# My loading gif animation is not working

Tags: javascript, html, gif

I have a loading GIF: [image: loading GIF]

But when I show the div with the GIF, the animation doesn't work, the GIF stay static like a image:

[image: Static Image]

HTML code of my div:

```
<div id="modalPDF" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div id="carregando">
                    <img alt="" src="imagens/refresh.gif"> 
                        <h4>Aguarde, gerando Arquivo...</h4>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript code that show the div:

```
$('#modalPDF').modal('show');
```

OBS: After show the Loading GIF, i running a recursive method with a lot of JS processing.

Comment: Are you running a ton of JS after displaying that gif? Because JS will block GIF animations.

Comment: Yes, after show gif, i call a recursive method.

Comment: Call your recursive function like `setTimeout(() => recursive(x,y,z), 0)` instead. The 0 ms delay will give the UI a chance to re-render.

Comment: This work, but just in Google chrome, in IE does't work

Comment: use a CSS animation loader, much faster and also avoid some issues like this?

Comment: @DanielH, you have any exemple of CSS animation loader?

Comment: @sergioBertolazzo google's loader https://codepen.io/jczimm/pen/vEBpoL

Comment: @sergioBertolazzo this is slack loader, even better, it is only one line of html, dynamically append it to <body> when you click submit etc, remove it once loading finished etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not an answer to your gif things, but as an alternative solution to your problem.

Use a CSS loader instead of a gif, this will load faster and much more browser friendly.

To use, you just need to call `screenLoader_Global()` to show it and call `remove_screenLoader_Global()` to remove it, note here I used jQuery but you can use pure js to write the same function easily.

The idea is simple, show and hide the CSS loader using js.

```js
// loader (after submit)
$('input[type="button"]').on('click', function(e) {
  //display loader
    screenLoader_Global();
  //just for testing, remove loader
    setTimeout(function() {
      remove_screenLoader_Global();
    }, 3000);
});


/*-----------------------------------------------------
  global screen loader add/remove
 ------------------------------------------------------*/
function screenLoader_Global() {
  $('<div class="loader-mask"><div class="loader"></div></div>').appendTo('body');
}

function remove_screenLoader_Global() {
  $('.loader-mask').remove();
}
```

```css
/*-----------------------------------------------
 css loader (slack style)
-----------------------------------------------*/

.loader {
  position: relative;
  width: 5em;
  height: 5em;
  transform: rotate(165deg);
}

.loader:before,
.loader:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  display: block;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  border-radius: 0.5em;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.loader:before {
  animation: slackbefore 2s infinite;
}

.loader:after {
  animation: slackafter 2s infinite;
}

@keyframes slackbefore {
  0% {
    width: 1em;
    box-shadow: 2em -1em rgba(225, 20, 98, 0.75), -2em 1em rgba(111, 202, 220, 0.75);
  }
  35% {
    width: 5em;
    box-shadow: 0 -1em rgba(225, 20, 98, 0.75), 0 1em rgba(111, 202, 220, 0.75);
  }
  70% {
    width: 1em;
    box-shadow: -2em -1em rgba(225, 20, 98, 0.75), 2em 1em rgba(111, 202, 220, 0.75);
  }
  100% {
    box-shadow: 2em -1em rgba(225, 20, 98, 0.75), -2em 1em rgba(111, 202, 220, 0.75);
  }
}

@keyframes slackafter {
  0% {
    height: 1em;
    box-shadow: 1em 2em rgba(61, 184, 143, 0.75), -1em -2em rgba(233, 169, 32, 0.75);
  }
  35% {
    height: 5em;
    box-shadow: 1em 0 rgba(61, 184, 143, 0.75), -1em 0 rgba(233, 169, 32, 0.75);
  }
  70% {
    height: 1em;
    box-shadow: 1em -2em rgba(61, 184, 143, 0.75), -1em 2em rgba(233, 169, 32, 0.75);
  }
  100% {
    box-shadow: 1em 2em rgba(61, 184, 143, 0.75), -1em -2em rgba(233, 169, 32, 0.75);
  }
}


/* position to center */

.loader {
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 2.5em);
  left: calc(50% - 2.5em);
}


/**
 * disable background
 */

.loader-mask {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 9998;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  display: table;
  transition: opacity .3s ease;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
  <form method="post">
    <tr>
      <td colspan="5" align="right">
        <input type="button" class="submit btn btn-success farmlead-green fl-btn-submit" value="Submit" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </form>
</table>
```

Comment: I am not sure how to integrate this with a form submit. Whenever I click submit and the def submit() ran, this animation stopped halfway and the new render_template loaded